# how to do the calculation with different signs

Tags: r, string

I have a df and I want to do a simple calculation using `test*factor`. How could I take care of  the signs in front of the value?

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(test = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("<=1.5", 
"<5", ">=1", ">7.8", "6"), class = "factor"), factor = c(2, 4, 
6, 9, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(outcome = str_c(str_remove(test, "\\d+"), factor *
     as.numeric(str_extract(test, "\\d+"))))

#>   test factor outcome
#> 1  >=1      2     >=2
#> 2   <5      4     <20
#> 3    6      6      36
#> 4  >78      9    >702
#> 5 <=15      8   <=120
```

---

Or with `parse_number`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(outcome = str_c(str_remove(test, "\\d+"),
    factor * parse_number(test %>% as.character())))

#>   test factor outcome
#> 1  >=1      2     >=2
#> 2   <5      4     <20
#> 3    6      6      36
#> 4  >78      9    >702
#> 5 <=15      8   <=120
```

---

With decimals:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(outcome = str_c(str_remove(df$test, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
   factor * parse_number(test %>% as.character())))

#>    test factor outcome
#> 1   >=1      2     >=2
#> 2    <5      4     <20
#> 3     6      6      36
#> 4  >7.8      9   >70.2
#> 5 <=1.5      8    <=12
```

Answer (score 6):

We can try

```
transform(
    df,
    outcome = paste0(gsub("\\d","",test),as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", test)) * factor)
)
```

which gives

```
  test factor outcome
1  >=1      2     >=2
2   <5      4     <20
3    6      6      36
4  >78      9    >702
5 <=15      8   <=120
```

Answer (score 5):

We could use `str_replace` - in the pattern, match one or more digits (`\\d+`) and replace with a function to multiply with the `factor` column after converting to `numeric`

```
library(stringr)
df$outcome <- str_replace(df$test, "\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) * df$factor)
```

-output

```
df$outcome
[1] ">=2"   "<20"   "36"    ">702"  "<=120"
```

---

For the updated, change the `\\d+` to include the decimal as well

```
str_replace(df$test, "[0-9.]+", function(x) as.numeric(x) * df$factor)
[1] ">=2"   "<20"   "36"    ">70.2" "<=12"
```

Answer (score 5):

One more. Here we use `parse_number` to multiply and then `paste` after removing the numbers from `test` column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% 
  mutate(outcome = paste0(str_replace(test, '\\d+', ''), factor*parse_number(as.character(test))
         ))
```

```
  test factor outcome
1  >=1      2     >=2
2   <5      4     <20
3    6      6      36
4  >78      9    >702
5 <=15      8   <=120
```

Answer (score 4):

And another solution using `separate`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    separate(test, 
             into = c("temp1", "temp2"), 
             sep = "(?<=\\D|^)(?=\\d+)", 
             remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(
    temp3 = as.numeric(temp2)*factor,
    outcome = str_c(temp1, temp3)
    ) %>%
  select(-matches("temp"))
  test factor outcome
1  >=1      2     >=2
2   <5      4     <20
3    6      6      36
4  >78      9    >702
5 <=15      8   <=120
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` and `stringr`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, outcome := str_c(str_remove(test, "[0-9.]+"), as.numeric(str_extract(test, "[0-9.]+")) * factor)]
```

**Output**

```
    test factor outcome
1:   >=1      2     >=2
2:    <5      4     <20
3:     6      6      36
4:  >7.8      9   >70.2
5: <=1.5      8    <=12
```

Or another option using `tidyr::extract`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  tidyr::extract("test", c("sign", "outcome"), "(\\D*)(\\d.*)", remove = F, convert = T) %>%
  mutate(outcome = paste0(sign, outcome * factor)) %>% 
  select(names(df), outcome)
```